# show me the latitude and longitude of that address

Tags: php, javascript

I want to implement the google geocoder in my website, so that if I give the address of any location it gives me the latitude and longitude of that address. Are there any tutorials?

Just like this website: http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html

In this website I give the location of the address and it gives me the latitude and longitude of that address, I want to do this, using php and javascript.

Comment: Please just edit your question to provide additional information.

Comment: @user604273 I think you want reverse-geocoding. I've updated my answer to point at the appropriate place in the Google Maps documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official [Google Maps docs](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#ReverseGeocoding), and the [accompanying tutorials](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse.html) are really pretty good. **edit:** link now points to the docs.

Comment: My brother it can not given me the latitude and longtitude of that location, I want to take the value of latitude and longtitude by given him the address or location..